# jQuery nested sortable - drag new element and connect it between

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

i have this problem - see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomasmrazko/zxznggmk/2/)

```
see code in jsfiddle
```

I want to drag orange box (outside of sortable) and place it between red and blue box - not inside to inner sortable, but between it.

But there is a problem that big green placeholder is not creating when i am hovered on inside sortable.

I tried to explane it in [this video](http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/con1j6egZc) (see it full)

Is there a solution for this problem? Can you try to help me, please?

Comment: what you mean by this ?  "I want to drag orange box (outside of sortable) and place it between red and blue box"

Comment: I mean that i Want to take orange box (at top, it is an external object) and drag it into sortable. BUT: there are two types of sortable - 1. sortable blocks (red and blue box) and 2. sortable items in block (squares in red and blue box)

and i want to be able to dropp orange box (external object) not just inside the sortable blocks (second type of sortable) but also between red and blue block...

Comment: ok now i got the complete requirement.